# AWS .NET SDK - Console Project Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-framework, sdk

I don't see an AWS console project options under "create a new project" in VS.

.NET SDK downloaded and installed on Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

I have tried downloading SDK directly and using NuGet package manager.

I have tried this with the 2017 and 2019 community version of visual studio.

I can see the AWS explorer and it works just fine.

Screen shot from the user guide:

[image: Screen shot from the user guide]

What am I missing? Do I need to move templates manually to an install location?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS2019 as of late Apr 2019, the new Project template pick screen doesn't show the legacy AWS Console project template.

To get an AWS enabled console project follow these steps:

1. Create new Console Project.  Use template -> Console App (.NET Framework) - **not** Console App (.NET Core)
2. Add the AWS SDK to your [project via NuGet package manager command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-nuget.html#net-dg-nuget-pkg-manager).

> Tools menu, select Nuget Package Manager, and click Package Manager Console.

3. Type this command:
   `Install-Package AWSSDK` - see page from step 2.  The AWS will download and install into your project automatically.
4. Check your project references and there should not be any errors and the AWS library is linked and listed.

[image]

I imagine MS or AWS will fix this soon.  Use this method to create one in the meantime.